# Moduli Spaces in Representation Theory of finite Groups

Tags: representation-theory

Recently I did work on Representation Theory of Finite Groups, in particular $p$-groups and recently I had a problem with something and I was wondering if I can put some geometry on that. So I thought that maybe an intresting case for further investigation would be the moduli spaces (if they do exist in that particular case of course) that we can derive from algebraic objects. I do know that I ask something quite vague, but do you know any reference which deals with moduli spaces in Representation theory?

Comment: Yes, there are notions known as character varieties and representation varieties. You can find a lot of reference by just googleing these terms.

Comment: Thank you for your response, to be honest i did find some sources while back for the representation varieties, however they are papers and some files in arXiv. I was wondering if there does exist any more "concrete" version of them, like a book for instance, or a chapter in some book for representation thoery that i don't already know.

Comment: Hi, Lubotzky and Magid have written a book called Varieties of Representations of Finitely Generated Groups.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i do really appreciate it!